# unexpected behaviour while inserting into database, phonegap sqliteplugin

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have written a method to first display the contents of database as listview and upon clicking on the listview i will display a popup to enter the student name.

Upon entering the student name i will check in the database whether the name exists, if name exists i will alert saying name already exists else i will write the date into database

```
$('#storedList').children('li').off('click').on('click', function () {
                 name = $.trim($(this).text());

         $("#existing_Name").popup('open');

         $('#exisitng_Namebutton').on('click', function(e) {


            var existname = document.getElementById('existingname');
            createname = $.trim(existname.value);

         //});

            if(createname.length!=0){

            db.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM SCHOOL WHERE  Std_name="' + name + '" and CreatedDate="'+createname+'" ', [] ,CheckingAllignSuccess,errorCB);
            }); 

            }
            else{
            alert("please enter the value");
            }
         });

        });




       }

    }


function Insertdbexisiting(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO SCHOOL (Std_name, CreatedDate) VALUES ("' + name + '","' + createname + '")');
}   


function successCBexisting(){

Displaylist(); 

   //window.open("list.html#Homelist");
   $.mobile.changePage( "#Homelist", { 
            transition: "slide",
            reverse: false,
        });

} 


var CheckingAllignSuccess = function(tx, resultallign){

if(resultallign.rows.length == 0){
    db.transaction(Insertdbexisiting, errorCB, successCBexisting);
    }else
    alert("Student name already exists");
}
```

This works fine while adding the first value.

while adding the second value even though the second value is not present i get an alert message saying "Student name already exists".

when i debugged i noticed `db.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM SCHOOL WHERE  Std_name="' + name + '" and CreatedDate="'+createname+'" ', [] ,CheckingAllignSuccess,errorCB);
            });` is calling 2 times if i am inserting data for 2nd time. it calls 3 times if i am inserting data for 3rd time

what is the mistake i am doing?. how will i prevent it?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by adding `off('click')` to `$('#exisitng_Namebutton').on('click', function(e) {` i just made it has `$('#exisitng_Namebutton').off('click').on('click', function(e) {` and it is working fine.

This idea was suggested by Gajotres in one of his answers in SO.